# Firebase Cloud Function - Create Triggers after delete

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Database in my app and have a cloud function trigger for on update and create.

I have a scenario in app where data created and than deleted in app
when internet offline and later when connected to internet somehow the create event in cloud function is triggered and i am updating some common fields but while it gets updated / before it gets updated the delete action in queue from app occurs and later that ref child remains only with the updated keys.

I want to terminate create event ongoing async code in Cloud Function if delete is occurred.

Hope i explained my scenario clearly. if any confusion please ask in comments.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: If you're saying that you don't like that triggers can be executed out of order, you should know that that's an expected situation. You can't force ordering with Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson: I want to terminate create event ongoing async code if delete is occurred.

Comment: You can't.  It will trigger.  You need to detect this case in your code.

Comment: @DougStevenson And how exactly ?
because my question was "I want to terminate create event ongoing async code in Cloud Function if delete is occurred."

Comment: You will need to get creative for this.  Maybe write some information in another location of the database saying that you saw a delete that didn't match existing data expect from a prior create.  This is sometimes called a "tombstone".